# Importing Python Tkinter script changes default radiobutton value

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two programs, let's say a.py and b.py, both using tkinter to make a basic GUI.

a.py looks something like this:

```
# a.py
import tkinter as tk
import b

window = tk.Tk()

def start_b():
    b.start_gui()
startButton = tk.Button(window, text='text', command=lambda: start_b())
startButton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

and b.py looks something like this:

```
# b.py
import tkinter as tk

def start_gui():
    window = tk.Tk()

    sortType = tk.StringVar(value='this should be default')
    selectMe = tk.Radiobutton(window, text='Select me!', variable=sortType, value='this should be default', tristatevalue=0)
    selectMe.pack(anchor='w')
    dontSelect = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="Don't select", variable=sortType, value='', tristatevalue=0)
    dontSelect.pack(anchor='w')

    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_gui()
```

I want the default selection of the radiobuttons in b.py to be the "selectMe" button. I have done this by setting the StringVar to the same value. This works if you run b.py directly, but for some reason, if you run it via the button from a.py, "dontSelect" is defaulted. Why is this happening?
Problem is directly reproducible with the code provided, by the way.

Comment: The problem is related to creating two instances of `Tk`. There's almost never a good reason to do that.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bryan Oakley! By changing `window = tk.Tk()` in b.py to `window = tk.Toplevel()` it now works.